# IndexError: list index out of range - API

Tags: python, index-error

Hi I am generating random `data to csv` file based on `Opensea API`. Problem is I am limited by the list size on the API. Is there a way to get around that?

Here is my code:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets?collection=bit birds&order_direction=asc&offset=' + (str(x)) + '&limit=1')
jsonResponse = r.json()
            
name = jsonResponse['assets'][0]['name']
description = jsonResponse['assets'][0]['description']
            
print('Name: ' + name)
print('Description: ' + str(description))
```

And I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File
"d:\generate-bitbirds-main\generate-bitbirds-main\bird_data\bitbird_generation_script_w_csv4.py",
line 1855, in <module>
name = jsonResponse['assets'][0]['name'] IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: The assets list in the response is empty, presumably. You can't get an item from an empty list.

Comment: Make this a running script. The error says that the list is empty. There isn't much we can say about that, except that you either need to check your data before use or catch the exception and do whatever you think is sane in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with APIs, it is good practice to check first if the request was successful before accessing the response. You may call [r.raise_for_status()](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status) first and handle the error scenario. Then before accessing the list, check first if it is not empty.

```
r = requests.get(...)
try:
    r.raise_for_status()  # Check if the request was successful
    jsonResponse = r.json()  # Check if the response is in JSON format
except requests.HTTPError, JSONDecodeError:
    # Handle error scenario
else:
    if jsonResponse['assets']:  # Check first if there are assets returned
        # Proceed as usual
        name = jsonResponse['assets'][0]['name']
        description = jsonResponse['assets'][0]['description']
    else:  # This means that the assets are empty. Depending on your use case logic, handle it accordingly.
        # Handle empty assets scenario
```